# websphere MQ explorer on windows

Tags: queue, ibm-mq, channel

I am a very beginner to WebSphere MQ world and this is what I'm looking for:

I have to create a simple system with 2 Machine (sender and receiver) to share messages on a queue:

PC 1 sender --> Queue --> PC 2 receiver

Both machines are Windows based and actually are on the same physical PC using virtualbox P1 (host) and PC 2 (guest)

Here is what I have done following online guides:

PC 1 sender:

1. Websphere MQ (full trial) installed
2. on MQ Explorer:

   - Queue Manager "QM.01" created
   - local Queue "Q.01" created with use=Transmission
   - channel sender "CH.01" created with queue=Q.01 and some doubts on connection which actually is 1414

PC 2 receiver:

- only MQExplorer installed
- try to create a remote queue manager with sender IP, 1414 port, and
  CH.01 channel --> error 2539 (something wrong on PC 1 configuration
- try to create a remote queue manager with sender IP, 1414 port, and
  default SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel --> error 4036 (something wrong
  with account authentication, I tryed to use the same "Adminitrator@PC
  1" user. I've also tried to create the remote queue manager on PC 1
  itself with the same result)

I suppose my error could be on PC 1 channel, its icon has a yellow or blue triangle and status=trying are not good.

Ps. forgive me if some setting name are not matching the English version, I have to translate them.

---

Now that I've been able to configure a remote `QMgr` on client PC I would learn how to write a simple program (maybe in `Java`) to read from a queue on the remote queue manager.

I've found a few guides but, before starting in Java, I tried to test `amqsget` and `amqsput` from command prompt.

There are no problems from the server machine (with `Websphere` full trial installed) but the console can't recognize the command from the client (with both `Websphere client` and `MQ Explorer` installed)

Where are my mistakes, or what passage have I missed?

Comment: Please read WebSphere MQ Quick Beginnings.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an application that needs to talk to a QMgr over the network, you create SVRCONN channels such as SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN.  The application using a SVRCONN channel is able to open queues directly and put or get messages from them.  There is no need to create a transmission queue or set USAGE=XMITQ in order for client applications to work.

When you have two QMgrs that need to communicate, you connect them using MCA channels.  On the sending QMgr, these include SENDER, SERVER and CLUSTER SENDER.  On the receiving QMgr there would include RECEIVER, REQUESTOR or CLUSTER RECEIVER channels.  Any of the outbound channels (SDR, SVR or CLUSSDR) require a transmission queue.

In the example you described, there is only one QMgr therefore no SDR, SVR or CLUSSDR channel is required.  You will need to use a SVRCONN such as SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN.  You did not mention having defined a listener but apparently you did or else you would not have received a 2539 MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR message.  The reason you get 2539 is because you are attempting to connect with a client to a channel designed for QMgr-to-QMgr connections.  The 4036 is because the configuration is incorrect.

- Delete CH.01 and redefine it as a SVRCONN channel.
- Alter Q.01 with USAGE=NORMAL
- Configure WMQ Explorer to connect to CH.01.
- As Shashi mentioned, take a look at some of the basic docs.  These include...

  - [Introduction to WebSphere MQ](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mq50040_.htm)
  - [Designing a WebSphere MQ architecture](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zl00110_.htm)
  - The Quick Beginnings manuals have been broken up but the main sections are [indexed here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zx00006_.htm).

You may also wish to review the WMQ Security Lab for V7.1 and earlier posted at [T-Rob.net](http://t-rob.net/links).  Although it is a security lab, it comes with scripts that build the lab environment, including SVRCONN and SDR/RCVR channel pairs, as well as an extensively illustrated lab guide.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response,

Following your indication I've understood I don't need two QMgr as I supposed,
but only one on the sending machine.
Therefore I have changed the query usage to normal, deleted the channel and leave other configuration by default:
SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel and LISTENER.TCP on 1414 port are automatically created.

I've tried also to redefine a channel named CH.01 as a SVRCONN channel
 
(Channel > new > server connection channel; and then choose between SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN, SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN or SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)
but unfortunately I wasn’t able to "Configure WMQ Explorer to connect to CH.01".

Anyway every attempt I have made to connect from the second PC are now ended with a AMQ4036 error; even if I’ve set in the CH.01 MCA Properties the ID user as my PC administrator and I have enabled the user identification on PC 2 as administrator@PC 1.

What I'm trying to achieve is to replicate an application used by company which receives data from a remote queue.
The queue connection specification given for test are: Server Name/IP, Port and Channel name.
This is the reason why I'm trying to replicate it creating a  QMgr on the receiving PC, because when I tried with the default test information on my company machines it worked creating a QMgr with all the test queues avilable.

I'm now on holiday and I can't have more specific information about my company settings but I hope to be able to replicate a configuration like that.

Regards,
Flavio.

Comment: I have modified my PCs names and workgroup in order to avoid windows authorization problems.
Now I’m able to create a QMgr on PC 1 (websphere full trial installed) with a local queue and access the queue by setting a remote QMgr on PC 2 (websphere explorer only).

Therefore I should be able to recreate the starting situation to study how access the message on a remote queue from an application on PC 2.

Unfortunately amqsget and amqsput command seems to work only on PC 1 original QMgr (I’ve tried also to install MQ client only on PC 2).

Thank you again for your support.
Flavio.